# Error while building GLFW using CMake and Visual Studio 2019 on Windows

Tags: c++, cmake, windows-10, visual-studio-2019, glfw

I have been configuring GLFW API by its source code using CMake and visual studio 19 on windows 10 for my project. I am getting a build error `/W3: No such file or directory gcc.exe`. I have installed `MinGW` using command `choco install mingw -y` and added installation `bin` path in the environment variables path.

CMakeLists changes for the glfw

```
set(GLFW_BUILD_DOCS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
set(GLFW_BUILD_TESTS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
set(GLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
add_subdirectory(glfw)
```

If I comment out the `add_subdirectory(glfw)` then I am able to build the rest of my project successfully.

Could someone please help me to get rid of this error?
Thank you!

Please find the error output below:

```
 [18/74] Building C object third_party/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_init.c.obj
  FAILED: third_party/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_init.c.obj 
  C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/bin/cmake.exe -E time C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\gcc.exe -DUNICODE -DWINVER=0x0501 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_GLFW_USE_CONFIG_H -D_UNICODE -Ithird_party/glfw/src -I../../../third_party/glfw/src -Ithird_party/glfw/src/glfw_autogen/include -I../../../third_party/glfw/include -I../../../third_party/glfw/deps/mingw -g -flto -fno-fat-lto-objects /W3 -std=c99 -Wdeclaration-after-statement -MD -MT third_party/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_init.c.obj -MF third_party\glfw\src\CMakeFiles\glfw.dir\win32_init.c.obj.d -o third_party/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_init.c.obj -c ../../../third_party/glfw/src/win32_init.c
C:\dev\robo-galaxy\supernova\out\build\x64-Debug\supernova\gcc.exe : error : /W3: No such file or directory
  Elapsed time: 1 s. (time), 1.072 s. (clock)
  [19/74] Building CXX object sandbox/CMakeFiles/SandboxApp.dir/src/sandbox_application.cpp.obj
  Elapsed time: 5 s. (time), 4.859 s. (clock)
  [20/74] Building C object third_party/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_joystick.c.obj
  FAILED: third_party/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_joystick.c.obj 
  C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/bin/cmake.exe -E time C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\gcc.exe -DUNICODE -DWINVER=0x0501 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_GLFW_USE_CONFIG_H -D_UNICODE -Ithird_party/glfw/src -I../../../third_party/glfw/src -Ithird_party/glfw/src/glfw_autogen/include -I../../../third_party/glfw/include -I../../../third_party/glfw/deps/mingw -g -flto -fno-fat-lto-objects /W3 -std=c99 -Wdeclaration-after-statement -MD -MT third_party/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_joystick.c.obj -MF third_party\glfw\src\CMakeFiles\glfw.dir\win32_joystick.c.obj.d -o third_party/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_joystick.c.obj -c ../../../third_party/glfw/src/win32_joystick.c
C:\dev\robo-galaxy\supernova\out\build\x64-Debug\supernova\gcc.exe : error : /W3: No such file or directory
```

Comment: It looks like somehow you are trying to build using the `gcc` compiler, but passing `/W3` as a flag. `/W3` is a flag for MSVC and possibly `clang-cl`, but not `gcc` -- which appears to be causing the error. `gcc` seems to be interpreting this as a file...? Something seems off here.

Comment: if (MSVC) target_compile_options(glfw PRIVATE "/W3")
elseif (CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "GNU" OR
        CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "Clang" OR
        CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "AppleClang")
    target_compile_options(glfw PRIVATE "-Wall")
endif()                                                                                                                                                https://github.com/glfw/glfw/blob/master/src/CMakeLists.txt

Comment: My best guess is you have some form of misconfigured project; but it's impossible to say without a lot more information. The snippet you linked should only take effect when compiling with a `cl` front-end -- which is correct. The fact that you are seeing `/W3` when building `gcc` even though it's guarded for MSVC makes me think that somehow you're in a badly configured project

Comment: Since you tagged this "`visual-studio-2019`", are you generating with `-G"Visual Studios 2019"` _and_ `-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=gcc`? I'm not 100% sure if those options are able to work together, so that could possibly be a factor. Maybe try re-generating without specifying `gcc` so that it uses `cl` directly, or just not using VS as your generated project type -- perhaps try one of the `Makefile`, `ninja`, or other project options, just to see if it works.

Comment: Thank you, @Human-Compiler ! This is an important piece of information. Let me start to properly configure the project first.

Comment: If I use header and lib only then I am able to build the project with the old configuration successfully. However, I'll prefer to keep source code that helps in debugging.